# Multiple filter aggregations vs Returning all buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm interesting in having sub-aggregrations but for specific keyword value.

```
 "aggregations" : {
        "Keyword" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "keyword"
          },
         "aggregations" : {
            "Concept" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "concept"
          }
        }
```

The following returns only the top 10 first, which does not necessary contains the values I'm interesting in.

I see two main ways of solving my issue:

- returning all the buckets and then selecting the ones I'm interesting in.
- adding filter aggregations for all the value I'm interesting in. So if I'm interesting in 10 keyword/values, I will perform 10 filter aggregations.

What is the best solution in term of performance?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Maybe give an example?

Answer (score 0):

> So if I'm interesting in 10 keyword/values, I will perform 10 filter aggregations.

This isn't necessarily true.

You can create a single filter that eliminates unwanted keywords and you can do this upfront at the query stage:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : [
        {
          "terms" : {
            "keyword" : [ "abc", "def", "ghi" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "Keyword" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "keyword"
      },
      "aggs" : {
         "Concept" : {
           "terms" : {
             "field" : "concept"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query stage would filter it down to just `abc`, `def`, and `ghi`. Then the aggregation would work as you expect, but only against documents with those values.